# Flutter: cannot delete Getx previous route

Tags: flutter, routes, flutter-getx, materialpageroute

I want to clear all previous routes in Getx. That's why I am using that function:

```
 static Future<void> removeAllAndNavigate(
    String nextScreen, {
    bool Function(Route<dynamic>)? predicate,
    dynamic arguments,
    int? id,
    Map<String, String>? parameters,   }) async {
    Get.offAllNamed(
      nextScreen,
      predicate: predicate,
      arguments: arguments,
      id: id,
      parameters: parameters,
    );   }
```

But today I realised that, it remember the previous route name. Cause after navigating new screen, I called

```
 print(Get.previousRoute);
```

and it show me previous route name. Where is the problem ?

Answer (score 0):

Use the `Get.clearRouteTree();` method to remove all the routes and clear the route tree from the navigation stack. It will completely reset the navigation history and remove all the `routes` pushed or replaced onto the stack.

```
ElevatedButton(
  onPressed: () {
    // Clear the route tree and start with a new screen
    Get.clearRouteTree();
    Get.to(NewScreen());
  },
  child: const Text("Go to New Screen"),
),
```